# Regular expression in Java for positive integers (excluding those starting with zero)

Tags: java, regex

I currently use "(\d){1,9}", but it fails to invalidate numbers such as "0134". The expression must only validate numbers that are positive INTEGERS. Thanks.

Comment: That's not doable in a reasonable way, if you want to prevent overruns as well. (2 147 483 648 and higher).

Comment: I guess i only need to make sure the string is made up with digits only without containing any other kinds of characters (such as +, -, &, ., etc), and it does NOT start with zero.

Comment: But you restrict it to 9 places. If you like to include longs or BigIntegers, that isn't apropriate, but "[1-9][0-9]*" - if it is intended to avoid overruns - it will only work occasionally. It will fail on over 78% of the possible numbers. :)

Comment: So you want a regular expression for decimal integer numbers in the range from 1 to 2147483647, correct?

Comment: @Roland Illig: yes, that would suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now you use the expression `[0-9]{1,9}`, so this clearly allows the number `0134`. When you want to require that the first character is not a zero, you have to use `[1-9][0-9]{0,8}`.

By the way: 0134 *is* a positive integer. It is an integer number, and it is positive. ;)

*edit:*

To prevent integer overflow you can use this pattern:

- `[1-9][0-9]{0,8}`
- `[1-1][0-9]{9}`
- `[2-2][0-1][0-9]{8}`
- `[2-2][1-1][0-3][0-9]{7}`
- `[2-2][1-1][4-4][0-6][0-9]{6}`
- …

I think you get the idea. Then you combine these expressions with `|`, and you are done.

Alternatively, have a look at the `Integer.valueOf(String)` method, how it parses numbers and checks for overflow. Copy that code and change the part with the `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex like below:

```
^(?!^0)\d{1,9}$
```

What you mean to say is positive integers *without leading zeroes* I believe.

Comment: You will probably have to replace the \ with \\ in Java. I was just giving the regex.