# Java Regex - String representation of non zero positive Integer

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm completely new to regex and wondering if I could get some ideas on resources/similar examples.

Basically I want to apply a regex to a String, which will be made up of several digits.  Rules being it cannot be a zero on it's own, and must be positive.  Was thinking along the lines of checking if first character is a '-', the whole string does not contain a '.' and that the string is not length 1 containing a 0..

The following post gave me a few ideas - [Regular expression in Java for positive integers (excluding those starting with zero)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998247/regular-expression-in-java-for-positive-integers-excluding-those-starting-with)

I would welcome some other ideas!

Comment: Could you clarify why the linked answers do not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: `s.matches("[1-9]\\d*")` goes on the entire string, 1 till 9 followed by any digits.

Comment: Why not just convert it into an integer?

Comment: http://regexpal.com/  Is a good tool to practice and test your expressions

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regular expressions are the appropriate way to test this. I would convert my `String` to an `int` using `Integer.valueOf()`. Like this:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(yourString) > 0) {
    // Do whatever you need to do...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thhe simplest regex is`\d+`. Jus duplicate back slash in java code